# Why is this Oracle SQL code failing (using trigger that restricts salary)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help with this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrict_salary BEFORE
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OF max_salary ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF :NEW.max_salary > 2500 
  THEN raise_application_error
  (-20202, 'Employee cant be over 5000');
END IF;
END;
```

I'm trying to copy the format I see here in my book. but it gives a pop-up that asks to define :NEW  .. any tips appreciate

[image]

Comment: Are you doing 'run statement' (control-enter) or 'run script' (F5)? I think you need the latter. That's assuming you get a dialog box for bind variables when you try to create the trigger, right? (And I see from your edit that you are seeing that dialog!)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use SQL Developer's "Run Script" button rather than the one to the left of it:

[image]